# Can you generate complex PDF files with Flex 4?

Tags: apache-flex, pdf-generation, flex4.5

I'm trying to understand if it is possible to generate complex PDF files with Flex.
By complex I mean add images, styled text (font-family, weight, columns) layout elements with large degree of control and so on.

I was looking at AlivePDF library but cannot understand if it can handle more complicated PDF generation than plain text.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[AlivePDF](http://alivepdf.bytearray.org/) is your best bet. It's also open source, so you can add more features on it if it doesn't do everything you want for your 'complex' pdf.

Other than that, you'll have to look into server side PDF generation.  I know [Adobe Livecycle](http://www.adobe.com/products/livecycle/pdfgenerator/) has a pdf generator and I'm sure there's other solutions out there.